# Как предотвратить выключения бота при ошибке в discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Скажите, пожалуйста, как мне возобновить работу бота при возникновении ошибки без конструкции try catch? **.catch()** - Желательно использовать в "**handler.js**".

"**index.js**"

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
const { eventsHandler } = require('./data/handlers.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Object.keys(GatewayIntentBits)], partials: [Object.keys(Partials)] });
client.config = require('./data/config.json');

client.login(client.config.bot.token).then(() => {
  eventsHandler(client);
});
```

"./data/**handler.js**"

```js
const fs = require('fs');

async function eventsHandler(client) {
  const folders = fs.readdirSync('./events');
  for (const folder of folders) {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${folder}`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
    for (const file of files) {
      const event = require(`../events/${folder}/${file}`);
      client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.run(...args, client))
    }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  eventsHandler
}
```

Comment: Можешь посмотреть в [сторону](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon). Или обрабатывать ошибку чтобы не вылетал, почему без try catch ?

Comment: Ну во первых он не запустит бота если не дублировать код, но мне нужно сохранять мобильность и красоту текста/кода.

Comment: "он не запустит бота если не дублировать код" это про nodemon? Нужно ошибку обрабатывать, которая крашит твой бот. Если он падает, значит красота текста/кода запредельная и в этой красоте не хватает обработки ошибки) По какой причине возникает ошибка, или это неизвестно?)